# Read in binary file

Tags: python

I want to know if there is a method to read a sequence of byte in a binary file.
I need to read a large number of value in different position of my file.

This is an example of what I am doing:

```
filein = open(name, 'rb')
liste_octet = [0, 8, 16, 20]
val = ''
for pos_octet in liste_octet:
    filein.seek(pos_octet, 1)
    val += filein.read(4)
```

Is it possible to do something like?

```
filein = open(name, 'rb')
liste_octet = [0, 8, 16, 20]
filein.read(octet)
```

Comment: Why bother reading multi times? Why not read once use multi times?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at the [mmap](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/mmap.html) module. It allows you access the file as a byte string, but without loading the entire file in memory:

```
import mmap

offsets = [0, 12, 32, 56]

with open(..., 'rb') as fp:
    mm = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), 0)

    # Load the octects in a list.
    octects = [mm[i:i+4] for i in offsets]
    # Or concatenate them into a byte string.
    val = b''.join(mm[i:i+4] for i in offsets)
```

Comment: This is not the same as what the OP is doing, it would give completely different results

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: indeed, I'm using absolute offsets, he's using SEEK_CUR. The approach may be sightly different, nevertheless this solves the problem of reading "large number of value in different position of my file" (mmap is pretty efficient for this sort of things).

Comment: The approach would be the same, you need to call `mm.seek(offset,1)` and use  loop the same as the OP's code,  mmap will be more efficient  if the OP is doing a lot of operations that would be system calls but it also requires contiguous block of address space to store the file

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: but then it wouldn't be a one-liner. And, as I understand the question, the OP wants a one-liner.

Comment: nope, but it would give the same answer as the OP's code, the only advantage to using a mmap is it is more efficient than using system calls like seek, read etc.., there is no one liner to match the OP's code.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: actually, there's a one-liner equivalent to the OP's code: `val = b''.join(mm[i:i+4] for i in itertools.accumulate(liste_octects, lambda a, b: a + b + 4))` -- still I do not want to provide a 1:1 equivalence, but rather let the OP learn the general approach and let him refine the solution to fit his needs.

Comment: i think your suggestion is what I need. I look for the use of mmap, and I think I had to use the offset option: my file is too large (more than 200Go). But I know the first position (in octet) in my file and the last position to read. 
So I try to do `mm = mmap.mmap(fp.fileno(), lenght = npoin, offset = start_octet)`.
But I have a _WindowsError: [Error 1132]  The base address or the file offset specified does not have the proper alignment_ I don't understand how to use the offset to mmap only a portion of my file?

Comment: @Adlane: I'm not a Win expert, but [it seems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583449/memory-map-file-offset-low) that Windows requires memory maps to be 64K-aligned. In other words, your `offset` can't be an arbitrary `start_octet`, but must be a multiple of 64K.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your comments and your help. My programm work for a small file.

Answer (score -1):

this seems like a job for [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). assuming you're reading characters:

```
with open(filename) as fin:
    for offest in offsets:
         fin.seek(offest)
         val += struct.unpack('s',fin.read(4))
```

Comment: I already use struct to decode my value. The problem is the multiple use of read. It slow my programm.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to do `filein.read(octet)`. However, reordering your existing code a little you could easily produce a small helper function:

```
def read_at_positions(filename, positions, length):
    data = []
    with open(filename, 'rb') as fh:
        for pos in positions:
            fh.seek(pos)
            data.append(fh.read(length))
    return data
```

Now you can use `read_at_positions(name, [0, 8, 16, 20], 4)` instead.

I've used the [`with`-statement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) for handling the opened file object, you might want to read something about it in [this excellent article](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).